# TSQL - Using variable in xp_regread

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to get the DefaultLog directory from a number of instances. The instancenames are stored in a temporary DB and I'm going through every row to get data about every instance.
How can I get this code to work or is there a better way? 
This is just a very small extract but shows my problem best. If needed i can post the rest as well

```
DECLARE @tempInstanceName varchar(100);
SET @tempInstanceName = 'TEST';
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.'+ @tempInstanceName + '\MSSQLServer','DefaultLog';
```

Solution:

```
DECLARE @tempInstanceName varchar(100),
    @REGKEY varchar(100);

SET @tempInstanceName = 'TEST';
SET @REGKEY = 'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.'+ @tempInstanceName +'\MSSQLServer'

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @REGKEY,'DefaultLog';
```

Comment: you need to use dynamic sql here. I had created a script for this, see if it can be useful to you: http://sqlandme.com/2012/01/05/sql-server-identifying-default-data-directory-for-multiple-instances-through-registry/

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. found a solution from another script. added as answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
SET @REGKEY = 'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.'+ @tempInstanceName +'\MSSQLServer'
```

And using @REGKEY instead works